# Is it possible to create a web ibeacon / eddystone with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5, ibeacon, eddystone

I'm currently starting to develop a huge project using Laravel as a framework to create a web platform. In our project and specification, we need to give the possibility to our customers to use beacons. Problem, if we have to provide beacons for all of them, it's not going to be easy on our side.

I already saw that it was possible (and I did it on my computer) to create a beacon / eddystone with this library : [Creating eddystone with Node.JS](https://github.com/don/node-eddystone-beacon)

I was wondering if one way or another, it's possible to use Node.JS on our server to let customers download an exe file with Node.JS included and their "virtual beacons" or no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your app in an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app - but depending on what you work on, you might also have to have a common api server which all of those apps can fetch data from.